# I get Error: invalid version specification ‘0,2’ when I use the function dm_draw() in r

Tags: r, dm

I want to use the function dm_draw() to visualize a [dm](/questions/tagged/dm) object but when I ran the command I get the error message " Error: invalid version specification ‘0,2’". I've tried the code included in the vignette "Visualizing dm objects" (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dm/vignettes/tech-dm-draw.html) and I get the same error message when I run the dm_draw() function.

```js
library(dm)
library(dplyr)
flights_dm_w_many_keys <- dm_nycflights13(color = FALSE)
dm_draw(flights_dm_w_many_keys)
```

I'm using dm version 0.2.7 and DiagrammeR 1.0.8. R version 4.1.2

I'm looking for a solution to visualize a dm object, it can be also different from dm_draw().
I hope someone can help me to get that done. Sorry for my broken English and thanks for your time, any type of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
       library(dm)
       library(dplyr)
       library(DiagrammeR)
       library(DiagrammeRsvg)
       
       # Use this function
       dm_draw_svg = function(dm,...) {
         if (!requireNamespace("DiagrammeRsvg", quietly = TRUE)) {
           stop(
             "Package \"DiagrammeRsvg\" must be installed to use this function.",
             call. = FALSE
           )
         }
         
         dm::dm_draw(dm = dm, ...) %>%
           DiagrammeRsvg::export_svg() %>%
           htmltools::HTML() %>%
           htmltools::html_print()
       }
       
       flights_dm_w_many_keys <- dm_nycflights13(color = FALSE)
       # plot
       dm_draw_svg(flights_dm_w_many_keys)
```

Output:
[image]